# How to make one bundle from several scripts using webpack?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack

How to make one bundle from several scripts using webpack? I'm trying to point several entries, but include just last, other just not seen how functions.

That's my app1:

```
function setCats() {
    alert('cat');
}

exports.setCats = setCats;
```

My app2:

```
function setDogs() {
    alert('dog');
}

exports.setDogs = setDogs;
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="bin/app.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>app.setCats()</script>
    <script>app.setDogs()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            './src/app1.js',
            './src/app2.js',
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
        library: 'app'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }]
    },
};
```

After building and running in browser alerted just dog and in console I have this mistake:

> index.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: app.setCats is not a function

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can only load one entry point in one webpack output bundle. If you use multiple, they are all loaded but only the last entry point is exported. This is often used to load polyfills before libraries, for example, since they don't export anything anyway.

To do what you want to do, you should simply make another higher-level file where you do this:

```
var setCats = require('./app1.js').setCats;
var setDogs = require('./app2.js').setDogs;

module.exports = {
    setCats: setCats,
    setDogs: setDogs,
};
```

Then simply use only that file as a single entry point (`entry: './src/app.js'`). After building it the bundled library will work and contain `app.setCats` and `app.setDogs`.